How to create a PDFFLowDocument with custom design repeated every pages
I'm building a PDF Document (using PDF4NET library) that requires a custom design for every page generated. I want to use the PDFFlowDocument class for its ease at handling multiple page generation
However, I'm unable to use PDFFlowDocument to build up a custom design, and worse at letting it replicate on every other page generated.
Using PDFFixedDocument I can do something like the following code to build some sort of custom design on a page. Is there a way to do the same using PDFFLowDocument and have that design embedded as pageDefaults for all other pages generated?
PDFFixedDocument doc = new PDFFixedDocument();
PDFPage page = doc.Pages.Add();
page.Canvas.DrawFormXObject(logo, X, Y, Width, Height);
page.Canvas.DrawLine(pen, X,Y, Width, Height);
page.Canvas.DrawRectangle(brush, X,Y, Width, Height);


You may want to indicate which PDF creation library you use.

I'm using PDF4NET library, I added that in the Title but for some reason it keeps getting Edited out.

You can handle the PageCreated event on the PDFFlowDocument class and draw your custom design on each page.
PDFFlowDocument doc = new PDFFlowDocument(fdd);
doc.PageCreated += Doc_PageCreated;

// ...

private static void Doc_PageCreated(object sender, PDFFlowPageCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Page.Canvas.DrawFormXObject(logo, X, Y, Width, Height);
    e.Page.Canvas.DrawLine(pen, X, Y, Width, Height);
    e.Page.Canvas.DrawRectangle(brush, X, Y, Width, Height);
}

Note: I work for the company that develops the PDF4NET library.

Thank you very much this worked perfectly!
